# c++ lock across methods

Tags: c++, multithreading, boost, locking

I have a data-structure that is not thread-save. Multiple threads are reading and writing to that data-structure in 2 methods. ( the order of calls is rather random) My approach to this problem was using a unique_lock like shown below :

```
struct test {

  void func1() {
    boost::unique_lock<boost::mutex> lock(_mutex);
    // modify data-structure
  }


  void func2() {
    boost::unique_lock<boost::mutex> lock(_mutex);  
    // modify data-structure
  }

   boost::mutex _mutex;
}
```

I though, that with this code, only one thread at a time is allowed to access the data, as the mutex is shared across the two methods.
But somehow may program triggers a bug in the data-structure, wich i am unable to reproduce in my single-threaded test-cases...

Do i have to use the boost::unique_lock in both methods and then call

```
lock()
unlock()
```

on it?

Comment: Use [`boost::scoped_lock`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_61_0/doc/html/boost/interprocess/scoped_lock.html) instead.

Comment: You may also use `std::mutex` and `std::lock_guard` for this case. There's no need to use boost for anything which is in STL

Comment: @JoachimPileborg Why does it make a difference in this case? A `scoped_lock` should be replaceable by a `unique_lock`.

Comment: It could be all kinds of other errors, e.g. undefined behavior somewhere in the methods of the class. E.g. if you have an out-of-bounds access it can have random effects.

Comment: General debugging advice: enable *all* warnings and fix all of them, use Valgrind, ASAN and TSAN.

Answer (score 0):

the locking mechanism, as described, was not the reason for the bug.
Well, actually it was ;)
Outside of the critical section i called

```
datastructure.empty()
```

because in an earlier version this method *was* threadsave.

Thanks to "Kerrek SB" for pointing on **thread-sanitizer**, as it's output guided me to the bug.